# css 2 column layout inside container

Tags: css, response, multiple-columns

I'm trying to implement layout where on desktop screen size we have 2 columns, and one column on mobile/tablets

is it possible to make this code:

```
<div class="posts-2-col">
    <div class="post">Post 1</div>
    <div class="post">Post 2</div>
    <div class="post">Post 3</div>
    <div class="post">Post 4</div>
    <div class="post">Post 5</div>
    <div class="post">Post 6</div>
</div>
```

to render like this:

[image]

(knowing that height of each post can e different)

Comment: Yeah - I recommend css "grid". https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 0):

I just put the fixed height to image a higher post

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eewztebv/1/)

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.posts-2-col{
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 -10px;
}

.posts-2-col .post{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 135px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="posts-2-col">
    <div class="post">Post 1</div>
    <div class="post">Post 2</div>
    <div class="post" style="height: 50px">Post 3</div>
    <div class="post">Post 4</div>
    <div class="post">Post 5</div>
    <div class="post">Post 6</div>
    <div class="post">Post 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, it's nice approach - but it will have white gaps - just make "height: 60px" and you will see